# "be accorded someone" or "be accorded to someone"?

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice

When the verb *accord* means "give or grant", should the passive voice be *accorded someone* or *accorded to someone*?

I came across several sentences in a book:

> The attention **accorded husband-wife relations** in Muslim teachings thus confirmed the indigenous view of matrimony as a desirable state, with the birth of children considered essential for the full attainment of adulthood.
>
> Similar processes occurred in Daoism, which percolated into Vietnam from southern China but never received the official patronage **accorded Confucianism**.

Shouldn't it be "accorded **to** husband-wife relations", as "given **to** husband-wife relations"?

Comment: The "to" is optional with "accord".

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically correct.

As can be seen from this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accorded%20him%2Caccorded%20to%20him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccorded%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccorded%20to%20him%3B%2Cc0), during the 19th century, the form with **to** was the most popular, but from 1880 onwards the form without **to** became more widely used, and remains so.

Using **accord** in this way is quite old fashioned and formal: **given to** would certainly be a more up-to-date way of expressing this idea.

Comment: The verb **accord** is more nuanced than **give**. It has the added sense of to give or grant what  is deemed *proper* or *fitting* to give.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, Agreed, but I don't see "what is deemed proper" as relevant to either of the example sentences that the OP provided.

Comment: "The attention accorded the subject in Muslim teachings" could be paraphrased as "The attention it was deemed fitting to devote to the subject in Muslim teachings"; the verb subtly reinforces the notion that it was an important topic.  I am responding to your remark that it is "quite old fashioned" (I would take issue with that) and that **given** is more up-to-date.